# How to create a range slider with different colored segments that fill in when slider is increased?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Trying to create a range slider like the one [here](https://www.nerdwallet.com/mortgages/how-much-house-can-i-afford/calculate-affordability). Can't seem to figure out to separate it into 3 different segments. Any help would be appreciated!

I was able to mess around with changing single colors. But still can't figure out how to do 3 different color segments.

CSS using Tailwind below

```
input[type='range'] {
        @apply w-full h-8 outline-none appearance-none rounded-3xl;
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7549ea 50%, #e7e4f2 50%);
    }

    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        @apply w-8 h-8 -mt-[.65rem] rounded-full appearance-none cursor-pointer bg-secondary-dark;
    }

    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        @apply h-2.5 appearance-none text-green mt-[-1px];
    }

    input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
        @apply w-8 h-8 rounded-full appearance-none cursor-pointer bg-secondary-dark;
    }

    input[type='range']::-moz-range-progress {
        @apply bg-primary;
    }

    input[type='range']::-ms-thumb {
        @apply mt-0;
    }

    input[type='range']::-ms-fill-lower {
        @apply bg-primary;
    }

    input[type='range'].slider-sm {
        @apply w-full h-[1.5625rem] outline-none appearance-none rounded-3xl;
    }

    input[type='range'].slider-sm::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        @apply w-[1.5625rem] h-[1.5625rem] -mt-[.45rem] rounded-full appearance-none cursor-pointer bg-secondary-dark;
    }

    input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
        @apply w-[1.5625rem] h-[1.5625rem] rounded-full appearance-none cursor-pointer bg-secondary-dark;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');
const slider_mask = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-mask')[0];

slider_mask.style.left = `${slider.value}%`;

slider.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  slider_mask.style.left = `${slider.value}%`;
});
```

```css
.multistepSlider {
  width: 380px;
  height: 60px;
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

.Affordable {
  width: 200px;
}

.Stretch,
.Aggressive {
  width: 80px;
}

.barContainer {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.bar {
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.multistepSlider>.barContainer>.step:nth-child(1)>.bar {
  background-color: #008254;
}

.multistepSlider>.barContainer>.step:nth-child(2)>.bar {
  background-color: #ffc764;
}

.multistepSlider>.barContainer>.step:nth-child(3)>.bar {
  background-color: #de2828;
}

.sliderContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 380px;
  top: 32px;
}

.slider-mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

input[type='range'] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="multistepSlider">
  <div class="barContainer">
    <div class="Affordable step">
      <label>Affordable</label>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Stretch step">
      <label>Stretch</label>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Aggressive step">
      <label>Aggressive</label>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sliderContainer">
    <div class="slider-mask"></div>
    <input type="range" id="slider" min="1" max="100" value="50" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I saw how to implement your request on site that you provide. and the way is split slider and 3 pieces slider bar background.
Draw 3 pieces and put slider over the slider-bar, and then demand on user input move translucent object to express disabled value.

I just using pure-CSS, so if you need convert to tailwind-CSS.

Comment: After some tweaking, it worked perfectly for me. Thank you!